# Not binding Datasource from Config Class to Controller with Autowired Annotation In Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hana, sap-cloud-platform

I am deploying a war file on SAP Neo trial and binding with Hana database instance. I am able to get a DataSource in `NeoConfig` Class but in Controller dataSource dependency injection, it's not working, object is null.

```
@Configuration
public class NeoConfig {
    DataSource ds = null;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NeoConfig.class);

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException, SQLException {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        // InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

        DataSource ds = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB");
        // ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB");

        DBInformation dbInfo = new DBInformation(ds.getConnection().getMetaData());
        log.info(dbInfo.toString());
        return ds;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    String returnMessage = null;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    // @Autowired ApplicationInstanceInfo instanceInfo;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String home(Model model) {

        Map<Class<?>, String> services = new LinkedHashMap<Class<?>, String>();

        if (dataSource != null) {
            services.put(dataSource.getClass(), toString(dataSource));
            model.addAttribute("services", services.entrySet());
            returnMessage = "Datasource";
        } else {
            returnMessage = "NoBinding";
        }
```

**Application.properties:**

```
server.contextPath=/

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class
```

**Context.xml**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DefaultDB"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="com.sap.jpaas.service.persistence.core.JNDIDataSourceFactory"/>
```

Comment: An `Autowired` field cannot be `null`. The application simply won't start if that is the case. Also why not simply use `spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/DefaultDB` to get the datasource. Your code has a connection leak (you are using a connection but aren't closing it!).

Answer (score -1):

Give bean name for DataSource

```
@Configuration
public class NeoConfig {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NeoConfig.class);

    @Primary
    @Bean("dataSource")
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException, SQLException {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        // InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

        DataSource ds = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB");
        // ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB");

        DBInformation dbInfo = new DBInformation(ds.getConnection().getMetaData());
        log.info(dbInfo.toString());
        return ds;
    }
}
```

now you can access this bean by `@Qualifier("dataSource")` or `@PersistenceContext(unitName ="dataSource")`

Comment: It won't work with `@PersistenceContext` and an `@Qualifier` nor the name is relevant when there is only a single datasource.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you suggest for same?